# Why can't I scrape the urls of the dispayed results of a search on a website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I've been trying to get the url of the first result of that kind of "results display page" and I can't, the html parser doesn't include it...

The link of the website : https://www.sobrico.com/#Prod_Live_Sobrico%5Bquery%5D=2608664131

I've been trying with different codes using BeautifulSoup, resquests, but nothing comes. I'm able to scrape many infos when I am on a product page like this one : https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608664131-coffret-lames-best-for-cutting-bosch-2608664131_SKU726760.html

But on a search results page, some part of the code, above all the one that contains the results shown, isn't available.. I hope to get an answer, it would really help.

Here is my code :

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://www.sobrico.com/#Prod_Live_Sobrico%5Bquery%5D=2608664131"
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, features='lxml')

for link in soup("a"):
    print(link.get("href"))
```

Comment: if the website uses javascript to fetch the content to the page BS, requests et all will not be able to see the the fetched content.

Comment: Help us to help you - Just in addition to @rasjani comment, providing some code as text will always be a good idea. Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead to get the **first item** on the search results page. Use a CSS selector to identify the item of interest. Then get the url by using the `get_attribute()` function.

#### Code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sobrico.com/#Prod_Live_Sobrico%5Bquery%5D=2608664131")

first_item = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#algoliasearch-hits li:nth-child(1) > article > a")
url = first_item.get_attribute("href")

print(url)

driver.close()
```

#### Output:

```
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608664131-coffret-lames-best-for-cutting-bosch-2608664131_SKU726760.html
```

#### Note:

If you want to get the urls from each of the 11 items on the page, you could iterate through them:

```
for i in range(1,12):
    url = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, f"div#algoliasearch-hits li:nth-child({i}) > article > a").get_attribute("href")
    print(url)
```

#### Output:

```
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608664131-coffret-lames-best-for-cutting-bosch-2608664131_SKU726760.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-coffret-starlockmax-4-pieces-bosch-best-of-heavy-duty-2608664132_SKUM89146.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-expert-2608644113-lame-scie-circulaire-260x30x2-8-mm-aluminium-96-dents-bosch-expert-2608644113_SKU744566.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608631319-5-lames-scie-sauteuse-hss-132-mm-metal-t318a-bosch-2608631319_SKU478349.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608641185-lame-scie-circulaire-190x30x2mm-bois-24-dents-bosch-2608641185_SKU491105.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608636431-lames-scie-sauteuse-t101-bif-special-for-laminate-pack-5-bosch-2608636431_SKU478354.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-expert-2608606131-bande-abrasive-ponceuses-x440-best-for-wood-and-paint-grain-80-610mm-bosch-2608606131_SKU490187.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-lames-scie-circulaires-bosch-construct-wood_SKUM75099.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-expert-2608644134-lames-scie-circulaire-for-high-pressure-laminate-56-dents-bosch-expert-2608644134_SKU744579.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608662431-lame-scie-oscillante-asz-32-sc-outils-multi-fonctions-bosch-2608662431_SKU777336.html
https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-2608664348-lame-scie-oscillante-bosch-starlock-carbure-metalmax-aiz-45-at-45mm-bosch-expert-2608664348_SKU777339.html
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it worked ! I have a little question : how to avoid an error and return something in case there's no result for a research like here : https://www.sobrico.com/p/bosch-expert-foret-perforateur-bosch-expert-sds-max-8x_SKUM124949.html#Prod_Live_Sobrico%5Bquery%5D=2607018277 thank you again!

Comment: you can use a try-except clause

Comment: Hi Scott, I've found it some minutes ago, thank you very much. Now I want to use selenium on other websites to extract the urls the same way, what does the CSS_SELECTOR need to find the url location ? I try to imitate the line you wrote but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've just added a little question to my comment, if you have time, don't hesitate :) (exemple of websites could be amazon or svh24)

Comment: you need to find the css selector for the item of interest. In the code above, it was searching for the `a` tag, but for other websites, you will need to inspect the site to see the most suitable selector. The selenium website provides some examples and a place to practice these types of selections.